# Word 2010: Customize ribbon to add GoBack (not WebGoBack) functionality

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

If you customize the ribbon, and select "All Commands" and pick off the Back and Forward buttons, you will find that these buttons will be disabled (Are these related to using Word as a web broswer?)

The functionality that I want to add as a button is related with teh command "GoBack" (not WebGoBack". I can Customuize my keyboard shortcuts, select All Commands and find the keyboard shortcut. This works, but I can't seem to find a way to put the functionaoity of this command as a button!!

Also, there seems not to be a command that goes FORWARD.  Again, GoForward is not what I need.

Comment: What functionality are you expecting for this "GoBack" to perform? Are you looking for the back feature, as in Shift+F5, to go back to the last place you were typing?

Comment: Yes. Shift + F5 is assigned to the GOBACK command. I'd just like to put a button on tghe Ribbon to do that. A Button for GoForward would be nice to, but I don't think it exists. The only button that I am able to add to the ribbon is a button that is associated with teh WebGoBack command, which has a shortcut of CNTRL + Left Arrow. I dont care about that.

Comment: Are you willing to create a simple macro and custom button?

Comment: Yes. This seems to be going where I expected. That the list of All Commands for buttons is not the same as the list of All Command for Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Sorry I've not responded until now. I will post an answer for you tomorrow, unless you've already resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there isn't a button for this action. So, you can create a custom one which calls a macro with the action you want.

**Create the Macro**

The macro is simple to make. Choose to record a macro from the button in the lower left corner.

[image]

Name it `GoBack` and make sure it stored for `All Documents` so it will be available all the time.

[image]

Click OK, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. **Don't do anything else because it will be recorded!**

Now click the macro button again to stop the recording.

[image]

**Create the button**

New commands are only allowed to be added to customer groups, so I'd suggest adding the button to the "Quick Access Toolbar" by doing the following.

Go into `Customize the Quick Access Toolbar` and choose `Macros` the drop down list for `Choose commands from`. You should see the macro you just created.

[image]

Highlight it and click the `Add` button between the panes. The command will show up on the right side.

You can the use the `Modify` button at the bottom to give it a display name and a custom button.

[image]

You should now have a new button on the Quick Access Toolbar to easily go back when you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to add the "GoForward", one can go to "Macros" and create a new macro based on the previous one for the forward case:

```
Sub GoBack()
'
' GoBack Macro
'
'
    Application.GoBack
End Sub

Sub GoForward()
'
' GoForward Macro
'
'
    Application.GoForward
End Sub
```